# SQL Server stored procedures, saving

Tags: sql-server-2008

I created a stored procedure and tested it.

The results were correct.

However, when I saved it, I do not see it in the folder with the other stored procedures that are on the server (under the Programmability folder)?

Comment: Its not automatically added, right click the Stored Proc root node & Refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to save a stored procedure, like a script, you need to execute the stored proc with a create statement at the top.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllData()
<define your SP here>
```

It will then show up in the stored proc folder.  To make changes, you "alter" the stored proc and run it again.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I had to use CREATE PROCEDURE then ALTER.

Comment: No problem.  I did the exact same thing the first time I tried to create one

Answer (score 2):

You may need to refresh the folder. Right click on the folder and click refresh.

Comment: Or hit `F5` with the database selected in object explorer on the left.